# そっち or そちら　What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, phrases, formality

そっち or そちら? The terms are used frequently in chat situations. I know that the terms mean there/you.　Is one term preferred over the other?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21194/9831 `those are the colloquial forms of こちら、そちら、あちら and どちら, respectively.`